# Rails How to link an email form with Sendgrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid

I was able to create a contact form that when a user clicks submit - its send an email and which i receive in my inbox. I would like to have that email be sent via sendgrid so that I can analyze analytics. I looked at the Gorails Sendgrid course and was able to send an email via sendgrid but I don't know how to apply that to my contact form. I have listed my code below, any help would be amazing. Thank you so much!

**new.html.erb (Contact Form which sends an email regularly when a user clicks submit)**

```
<div align="center">
<h3>Send A message to Us</h3>
  <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>    
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send Message", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-md"%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
@contact = Contact.new
  end
  def create
@contact = Contact.new(contact_params) 
@contact.request = request
if @contact.deliver
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
else
  flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
  render :new
end
  end
  private
  def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

**Sendgrid.rb (Within my config > initializers folder)**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'apikey',
  :password => Rails.application.secrets.sendgrid_api_key,
  :domain => 'tango.co',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:user_name => 'apikey',
:password => Rails.application.secrets.sendgrid_api_key,
:domain => 'tango.co',
:address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port => 587,
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

**Mailers Folder (I only have two files Notification and application none deal with my Contacts Form)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was missing for this. I needed to generate a mailer for contacts. With that completed and adding a line to my contacts_controller.rb, I was able to send my emails via sendgrid with no problemo :)

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController  
def new
@contact = Contact.new
  end
  def create
@contact = Contact.new(contact_params) 
@contact.request = request
if @contact.save
    ContactMailer.new_request(@contact.id).deliver_later
end
if @contact.deliver
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
else
  flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
  render :new
end
  end
  private
  def contact_params 
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
 end
end
```

Contacts Mailer

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer 
 def new_request
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I did the same gorails tutorial you did and was wondering how to apply it to a contact form same as you and while my code looks slightly different, this helped me find the missing pieces I needed. Oh and for those wondering, I can confirm this still works on Rails 6.